# Highcharts columns - fixed border width, remove spacing between the bars

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**TL;DR** Q: How do I force the fixed width of bar's border in Highstocks?

I need to display a histogram using Highcharts. I'd like to look it like this:[image: simple column chart]
that is, no spaces between the bars, and the fixed width border.

Now I've tried to do the same with Highcharts, but it seems that *some* of the bars overlap each other, and the border width is not constant:
[image: incorrect behavior of highcharts]
Here are the (significant) config options:

```
plotOptions: {
    series : {
        pointPadding : 0,
        groupPadding : 0,
        shadow       : false,
        borderWidth  : 1,
        borderColor  : 'black'
    }
}
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Each bar has own border, so between bars, border is "duplicated". It is defaulty behaviour of this kind of chart.

Comment: @SebastianBochan it is duplicated between *some* of the bars, not all of them. Also, please note that the border on the right side is smaller than the left-side. It seems to be some shadowing, althought it should be disabled...

Comment: I gave up trying to get this to work properly.  I use histograms all the time with Highcharts, and have simpyl accepted that there will be spacing anomalies...I have generally opted for leaving a tiny amount of space between the columns, which seems to minimize the bad effect.  it is very unfortunate, however, and should be fixed.  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/FnhRV/3/

Comment: According to the changelog ( http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog ), the newly released version improves the drawing sharpness for bars and columns.  I am personally noticing some improvement on this issue in my charts, though it is not perfect still

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `gridLineWidth`. You've set that correctly.

In addition you need to set the `minorGridLineWidth` that you have to set to 0

similar demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2Mv2/1/